# Getting the error in an extension 'The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint'

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

I'm adding thumbnailMaskView on top of thumbnailImageView and it works!

```
func setupViews() {

    addSubview(thumbnailImageView)
    addSubview(thumbnailMaskView)

    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: thumbnailImageView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-16-[v0]-16-|", views: thumbnailImageView)

    addConstraints([NSLayoutConstraint(item: thumbnailMaskView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: thumbnailImageView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)])
    addConstraints([NSLayoutConstraint(item: thumbnailMaskView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: thumbnailImageView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)])
    addConstraints([NSLayoutConstraint(item: thumbnailMaskView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: thumbnailImageView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)])
    addConstraints([NSLayoutConstraint(item: thumbnailMaskView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: thumbnailImageView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)])
}
```

I'm trying to extract that code to a `UIView Extension` with the following code:

```
extension UIView {

    func addOnTop(_ topView: UIView) {
        addConstraints([NSLayoutConstraint(item: topView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)])
        addConstraints([NSLayoutConstraint(item: topView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)])
        addConstraints([NSLayoutConstraint(item: topView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)])
        addConstraints([NSLayoutConstraint(item: topView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)])
    }
}
```

When using the `extension` function `thumbnailImageView.addOnTop(thumbnailMaskView)` I get the error:

> 2019-10-04 14:19:13.149081+0100 Rich People[1589:18861]
>   [LayoutConstraints] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the
>   constraint: 
>   (inactive)>   When added to a view, the constraint's items must be
>   descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the
>   constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is
>   assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout)
>   _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug. 2019-10-04 14:19:13.152718+0100 Rich People[1589:18861] [LayoutConstraints] View
>   hierarchy unprepared for constraint.  Constraint:
>       Container hierarchy: 
>   >   View
>   not found in container hierarchy: >     That view's
>   superview: > 2019-10-04 14:19:13.160046+0100 Rich
>   People[1589:18861] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view. 
>   Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of
>   the view?  That's illegal.
>   constraint:
>   (active)> view:>'

Comment: How do you use `addOnTop` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add constraints to a view then those should be for a child/descendant view , so it's better to use `activate`

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([  
    topView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor), 
    topView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor), 
    topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor), 
    topView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor) 
])
```

And it will add the constraints to the correct view

Comment: I are already added them to the view in addSubview(thumbnailImageView)
    addSubview(thumbnailMaskView), with those lines they will just occupy the all view

Comment: yes but this `thumbnailImageView.addOnTop(thumbnailMaskView)` add the constraints between the 2 views to `thumbnailImageView` which is incorrect as they should be added to the parent view of  `thumbnailImageView` try `thumbnailImageView.superView!.addOnTop` and it should work